# Pytest: test cases affects one another, freshly initialized object not empty

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I noticed some strange behaviour while using pytest to build and run unit tests on a python module I am building.

When running the test case separate it passes without problem.
But when running the complete test the test case fails.
Running the complete test in debug and adding a breakpoint in the test case shows that a newly created instance of an object is not as fresh as expected. It looks like the memory is reused from the same object in a previous test case, something you would not expect or want.

How can I solve these issues?

This is the test case:

```
def test_add_new_subfield_with_valid_parameters(self):
    # Given
    tag = '245'
    type = 'd'
    repeatable = True
    description = 'Title Statement'
    field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)

    # When
    subfield_tag = 'a'
    subfield_repeatable = False
    subfield_description = 'Title'
    field.add_SubField(tag=subfield_tag, repeatable=subfield_repeatable, description=subfield_description)

    # Then
    assert len(field.subfields) == 1
    assert field.subfields[0].tag == subfield_tag
    assert field.subfields[0].repeatable == subfield_repeatable
    assert field.subfields[0].description == subfield_description
```

Running it separately:

```
pytest -v .\tests\test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_add_new_subfield_with_valid_parameters     
======================================================================================================= test session starts =======================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.4.3, pluggy-1.3.0 -- C:\Users\vdvuursj\Documents\workspace\marc21\venv\Scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\vdvuursj\Documents\workspace\ISNI\marc21
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

tests/test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_add_new_subfield_with_valid_parameters PASSED                                                                                                                                   [100%] 

======================================================================================================== 1 passed in 0.01s ========================================================================================================
```

But when running all the tests in this file:

```
pytest .\tests\test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField

======================================================================================================= test session starts =======================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.4.3, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: C:\Users\vdvuursj\Documents\workspace\ISNI\marc21
collected 19 items

tests\test_marcfield.py ...F.F..F.....FFFFF                                                                                                                                                                                  [100%]

============================================================================================================ FAILURES =============================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________ TestMarcField.test_check_if_subfield_present ___________________________________________________________________________________________

self = <test_marcfield.TestMarcField object at 0x0000023E9FAC5CD0>

    def test_check_if_subfield_present(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)
    
        subfield_tag = 'a'
        subfield_repeatable = False
        subfield_description = 'Title'

>       field.add_SubField(tag=subfield_tag, repeatable=subfield_repeatable, description=subfield_description)

tests\test_marcfield.py:81:

... skipped the rest 

===================================================================================================== short test summary info ===================================================================================================== 
FAILED tests/test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_check_if_subfield_present - marc21.marc21.MarcException: Non-repeatable subfield a repeated for tag 245
FAILED tests/test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_add_new_subfield_with_repeatable_true - assert 2 == 1
FAILED tests/test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_init_with_no_subfields - assert [adummy, adummy] == []
FAILED tests/test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_return_new_instance_with_same_values - AttributeError: 'MarcField' object has no attribute 'indicators'
FAILED tests/test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_return_new_instance_with_different_memory_address - AttributeError: 'MarcField' object has no attribute 'indicators'
FAILED tests/test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_return_new_instance_with_new_subfields - AttributeError: 'MarcField' object has no attribute 'data'
FAILED tests/test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_add_multiple_subfields_with_different_tags - marc21.marc21.MarcException: Non-repeatable subfield a repeated for tag 245
FAILED tests/test_marcfield.py::TestMarcField::test_add_multiple_subfields_with_same_tag_and_repeatable_true - assert 4 == 2
================================================================================================== 8 failed, 11 passed in 0.34s ===================================================================================================
```

Debugging shows the following:

Right after the initialization of a new instance of the object MarcField, it already has a subfield in it list of subfields.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY8vN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TxKS.png)

I tried debugging the code (see description above), I cleaned the cache, restarted PyCharm etc etc.

I expect that each test case is independent from and not affacted by previous test cases.

Here are the other test cases in that file.

```py
import pytest
from marc21 import MarcField, SubField

class TestMarcField:

    #  Create a new MarcField object with valid parameters.
    def test_create_new_marcfield_with_valid_parameters(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
    
        # When
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)
    
        # Then
        assert field.tag == tag
        assert field.type == type
        assert field.repeatable == repeatable
        assert field.description == description
        assert field.has_indicators == True
        assert field.indicators == '  '
        assert field.subfields == []

    #  Add a new subfield to a MarcField object with valid parameters.
    def test_add_new_subfield_with_valid_parameters(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)
    
        subfield_tag = 'a'
        subfield_repeatable = False
        subfield_description = 'Title'
    
        # When
        field.add_SubField(tag=subfield_tag, repeatable=subfield_repeatable, description=subfield_description)
    
        # Then
        assert len(field.subfields) == 1
        assert field.subfields[0].tag == subfield_tag
        assert field.subfields[0].repeatable == subfield_repeatable
        assert field.subfields[0].description == subfield_description

    #  Set the value of the indicators attribute in a MarcField object.
    def test_set_indicators_attribute(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)
    
        indicators = '10'
    
        # When
        field.set_indicators(indicators=indicators)
    
        # Then
        assert field.indicators == indicators

    #  Check if a subfield with a given tag is present in a MarcField object.
    def test_check_if_subfield_present(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)
    
        subfield_tag = 'a'
        subfield_repeatable = False
        subfield_description = 'Title'
    
        field.add_SubField(tag=subfield_tag, repeatable=subfield_repeatable, description=subfield_description)
    
        # When
        is_present = field.is_subfield_present(tag=subfield_tag)
    
        # Then
        assert is_present == True

    #  Create a new MarcField object with repeatable set to True.
    def test_create_new_marcfield_with_repeatable_true(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
    
        # When
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)
    
        # Then
        assert field.repeatable == True

    #  Add a new subfield to a MarcField object with repeatable set to True.
    def test_add_new_subfield_with_repeatable_true(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)
    
        subfield_tag = 'a'
        subfield_repeatable = True
        subfield_description = 'Title'
    
        # When
        field.add_SubField(tag=subfield_tag, repeatable=subfield_repeatable, description=subfield_description)
    
        # Then
        assert len(field.subfields) == 1
        assert field.subfields[0].tag == subfield_tag
        assert field.subfields[0].repeatable == subfield_repeatable
        assert field.subfields[0].description == subfield_description


    #  Initializes a new instance of MarcField with mandatory parameters tag and type, and optional parameters repeatable, description, has_indicators, indicators, data, and subfields.
    def test_init_with_mandatory_and_optional_parameters(self):
        # Given
        tag = '001'
        type = 'c'
        repeatable = False
        description = 'Unique identifier'
        has_indicators = False
        indicators = ''
        data = '12345'
        subfields = []

        # When
        marc_field = MarcField(tag, type, repeatable, description, has_indicators, indicators, data, subfields)

        # Then
        assert marc_field.tag == tag
        assert marc_field.type == type
        assert marc_field.repeatable == repeatable
        assert marc_field.description == description
        assert marc_field.has_indicators == has_indicators
        assert marc_field.data == data

    #  Initializes the tag, type, repeatable, description, has_indicators, indicators, data, and subfields attributes with the values passed as parameters.
    def test_init_with_parameters_values(self):
        # Given
        tag = '001'
        type = 'c'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Description'
        has_indicators = False
        indicators = '12'
        data = 'Data'
        subfields = [SubField('a', True, 'Subfield A'), SubField('b', False, 'Subfield B')]

        # When
        marc_field = MarcField(tag, type, repeatable, description, has_indicators, indicators, data, subfields)

        # Then
        assert marc_field.tag == tag
        assert marc_field.type == type
        assert marc_field.repeatable == repeatable
        assert marc_field.description == description
        assert marc_field.has_indicators == has_indicators
        assert marc_field.data == data


    #  Initializes the subfields attribute with an empty list if no subfields are passed as parameters.
    def test_init_with_no_subfields(self):
        # Given
        tag = '100'
        type = 'd'

        # When
        marc_field = MarcField(tag, type)

        # Then
        assert marc_field.subfields == []

    #  Initializes the has_indicators attribute to True if the type is 'c' or 'd'.
    def test_init_has_indicators_true(self):
        # Given
        tag = '101'
        type = 'd'

        # When
        marc_field = MarcField(tag, type)

        # Then
        assert marc_field.has_indicators is True

    #  Initializes the has_indicators attribute to True if the type is 'c' or 'd'.
    def test_init_has_indicators_false(self):
        # Given
        tag = '001'
        type = 'c'

        # When
        marc_field = MarcField(tag, type)

        # Then
        assert marc_field.has_indicators is False

    #  Initializes the indicators attribute to '  ' if the type is 'c' or 'd'.
    def test_init_indicators(self):
        # Given
        tag = '101'
        type = 'd'

        # When
        marc_field = MarcField(tag, type)

        # Then
        assert marc_field.indicators == '  '

    def test_set_indicators(self):
        # Given
        tag = '101'
        type = 'd'
        indicators = '12'

        # When
        marc_field = MarcField(tag, type)
        marc_field.indicators = indicators

        # Then
        assert marc_field.indicators == indicators

    #  Initializes the data attribute to '  ' if the type is 'c' or 'd'.
    def test_init_data(self):
        # Given
        tag = '001'
        type = 'c'

        # When
        marc_field = MarcField(tag, type)

        # Then
        assert marc_field.data == '  '

    #  Should return a new instance of MarcField with the same values as the original instance
    def test_return_new_instance_with_same_values(self):
        # Given
        field1 = MarcField('001', 'c', description='Control Number', data='12345')

        # When
        field2 = field1.__copy__()

        # Then
        assert isinstance(field2, MarcField)
        assert field2.tag == field1.tag
        assert field2.type == field1.type
        assert field2.repeatable == field1.repeatable
        assert field2.description == field1.description
        assert field2.has_indicators == field1.has_indicators
        if field2.type == 'c':
            assert field2.data == field1.data
        else:
            assert field2.subfields == field1.subfields

    #  Should return a new instance of MarcField with a different memory address than the original instance
    def test_return_new_instance_with_different_memory_address(self):
        # Given
        field1 = MarcField('001', 'c', description='Control Number', data='12345')

        # When
        field2 = field1.__copy__()

        # Then
        assert id(field2) != id(field1)

    #  Should return a new instance of MarcField with subfields that are also new instances with different memory addresses than the original subfields
    def test_return_new_instance_with_new_subfields(self):
        # Given
        subfield1 = SubField('a', repeatable=True, description='Subfield A', value='Value A')
        subfield2 = SubField('b', repeatable=False, description='Subfield B', value='Value B')
        field1 = MarcField('100', 'd', description='Control Number', data='12345', subfields=[subfield1, subfield2])

        # When
        field2 = field1.__copy__()

        # Then
        assert id(field2.subfields[0]) != id(field1.subfields[0])
        assert id(field2.subfields[1]) != id(field1.subfields[1])


    #  add a new subfield with valid parameters
    def test_add_new_subfield_with_valid_parameters(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)

        # When
        subfield_tag = 'a'
        subfield_repeatable = False
        subfield_description = 'Title'
        field.add_SubField(tag=subfield_tag, repeatable=subfield_repeatable, description=subfield_description)

        # Then
        assert len(field.subfields) == 1
        assert field.subfields[0].tag == subfield_tag
        assert field.subfields[0].repeatable == subfield_repeatable
        assert field.subfields[0].description == subfield_description

    #  add a new subfield with repeatable=True
    def test_add_new_subfield_with_repeatable_true(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)

        # When
        subfield_tag = 'a'
        subfield_repeatable = True
        subfield_description = 'Title'
        field.add_SubField(tag=subfield_tag, repeatable=subfield_repeatable, description=subfield_description)

        # Then
        assert len(field.subfields) == 1
        assert field.subfields[0].tag == subfield_tag
        assert field.subfields[0].repeatable == subfield_repeatable
        assert field.subfields[0].description == subfield_description

    #  add multiple subfields with different tags
    def test_add_multiple_subfields_with_different_tags(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)

        # When
        subfield1_tag = 'a'
        subfield1_repeatable = False
        subfield1_description = 'Title'
        field.add_SubField(tag=subfield1_tag, repeatable=subfield1_repeatable, description=subfield1_description)

        subfield2_tag = 'b'
        subfield2_repeatable = False
        subfield2_description = 'Subtitle'
        field.add_SubField(tag=subfield2_tag, repeatable=subfield2_repeatable, description=subfield2_description)

        # Then
        assert len(field.subfields) == 2
        assert field.subfields[0].tag == subfield1_tag
        assert field.subfields[0].repeatable == subfield1_repeatable
        assert field.subfields[0].description == subfield1_description
        assert field.subfields[1].tag == subfield2_tag
        assert field.subfields[1].repeatable == subfield2_repeatable
        assert field.subfields[1].description == subfield2_description

    #  add multiple subfields with the same tag and repeatable=True
    def test_add_multiple_subfields_with_same_tag_and_repeatable_true(self):
        # Given
        tag = '245'
        type = 'd'
        repeatable = True
        description = 'Title Statement'
        field = MarcField(tag=tag, type=type, repeatable=repeatable, description=description)

        # When
        subfield1_tag = 'a'
        subfield1_repeatable = True
        subfield1_description = 'Title'
        field.add_SubField(tag=subfield1_tag, repeatable=subfield1_repeatable, description=subfield1_description)

        subfield2_tag = 'a'
        subfield2_repeatable = True
        subfield2_description = 'Subtitle'
        field.add_SubField(tag=subfield2_tag, repeatable=subfield2_repeatable, description=subfield2_description)

        # Then
        assert len(field.subfields) == 2
        assert field.subfields[0].tag == subfield1_tag
        assert field.subfields[0].repeatable == subfield1_repeatable
        assert field.subfields[0].description == subfield1_description
        assert field.subfields[1].tag == subfield2_tag
        assert field.subfields[1].repeatable == subfield2_repeatable
        assert field.subfields[1].description == subfield2_description
```

Comment: You are responsible yourself for ensuring that there are no dependencies between tests. In `pytest`, this is usually done using fixtures that clean up resources after the test (e.g. after `yield`). There is no way `pytest` itself can ensure that, as you are always able to change global state during a test. As you don't show your other tests, we cannot say what causes your specific problem.

Comment: Of course I can and will share my other tests.

Comment: This looks like the construction of `MarcField` has some side effect. Maybe it is persisted and not cleaned up after the test?